Can't run any API 34 emulators on Android Studio
I recently upgraded Android Studio to Koala. I am trying to run an emulator with API 34 but whenever I try the process just hangs on "waiting for all target devices to come online". I have tried creating a Pixel 8 API 34 emulator and a Pixel 7a, none of them launch. If I try API 33 everything works normally.
I have tried running it for an existing Java project and for a brand new Kotlin project but it doesn't work.
I am running Android Gradle Plugin 8.5.1.
Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?
